# How to put all paths of files of particular type in subdirectories into a text file in windows cmd?

Tags: java, for-loop, cmd, directory, javac

I am trying to create a sources txt file to pass to the javac compiler. In the text file, I need to have the paths of all the .java files in the subdirectories surrounded by speech marks, in case the folder names contain spaces, and any \ for the path need to be \\ because \ is escaped. With the text file I would run `javac -d \classes @sources.txt` . This works and I have tested it with paths I have written into sources.txt. However, I have been experimenting with trying to get the command line to create this file for me as it would be a hassle if there were more files and I had to write every single path.

So far I have tried running `for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /s /B *.java') do @echo "%A" >>sources.txt`. The dir command gets all the paths and the echo surrounds the commands with speech marks but when I try running the following command instead to switch the \ to \\ it doesn't work:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /s /B *.java') do @echo "%A:\=\\" >>sources.txt
```

This returns the "<thepath>:\=\\". What am I doing wrong?
FYI: this is directly in the cmd line and not ran from a file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this appears to be a Command Prompt, ([cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)) question, and not a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), (as shown in the other current answer), perhaps this will achieve what you intended:

```sh
(For /F "Delims=" %G In ('Dir "*.java" /A:-D /B /O:N /S 2^>NUL') Do @Set "}=%G" & %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /V /C "Echo !}:\=\\!") 1>"sources.txt"
```

Comment: How come you need to run the cmd.exe and you can't just run the echo command? Also, what are the options after cmd.exe?

Comment: @ThomasStokes, to find out the options for `cmd.exe`, use the same method as for almost every other command. In a Command Prompt window, type `cmd /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key. So you could do the same with `for /?`, `dir /?`, `set /?` and even `echo /?`. The additional call to `cmd.exe` is required to enable delayed expansion, `/V` to expand and substitute the backward slash in your temporary variable. Otherwise when the single line command is read and parsed before running, the variable using `!`'s is not seen as such and therefore not expanded as intended.

Comment: Okay, thank you. What about the 1>, why can't it just be>? And finally what is the 2^>NUL? Thanks for answering my questions!

Comment: It could be `>`, if you want to use lazy code, @ThomasStokes; I don't, so I will not. `2>NUL` will send any STDERR, _(error message)_, to the NUL device, instead of passing it on to the `Do` portion of the command. The idea is that if there are no `*.java` glob matches in the tree, then nothing will happen, _(as there will be nothing output to the `Do` portion command(s))_. The caret, `^` escapes the special characrer, `>`, so that it is not treated as a redirection symbol, when the parenthesized block is first parsed and run independently of the whole line.

Answer (score 4):

The substitution needs to be done on an environment variable, not on the loop variable.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D "*.java"') DO (SET "AA=%%~fA" & ECHO "!AA:\=\\!")
```

This can also be produced from the cmd.exe prompt by removing one of the PERCENT characters from the loop variable and using:

```
"%ComSpec%" /V:ON /C "ECHO OFF & (FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D "*.java"') DO (SET "AA=%~fA" & ECHO "!AA:\=\\!")) >>"sources.txt"
```

Comment: I see, thanks, but when I do this the variable isn't updated and the same thing is echoed?

Comment: Sorry, it needs delayed expansion enabled. Revised the answer.

Comment: What does echo off do?

Comment: Use the `ECHO /?` command to read what it does. Try the command with and without ECHO OFF and report the results. Remove `ECHO OFF & ` from the command to try it without.

Comment: I see, thanks. Having the command stops the echo command, later in the instruction,  from outputting the edited paths. Is there a way to write to the file instead of appending, so that the previous contents of the file is cleared? Thank you very much.

Comment: @ThomasStokes, change the `>>` redirection (append) to `>` which will overwrite any existing file. I used `>>` because it was in the question and I thought that is what you wanted.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But when I do that it only puts the last file path echoed into the text document?

Comment: @ThomasStokes, I have added another layer or PARENTHESIS characters around the FOR loop. Please try again.